# Algorithm to visit all nodes in an un-directed graph with greatest efficiency?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, path-finding

So I have the following layout:

[graph representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEIeR.png)

The objective is to collect all the yellow blocks by moving the white ball around. I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that will calculate an efficient path however I'm not too sure where to start.

Initially I thought about path finding algorithms like Djikstra and A* but they don't seem to fit with my goal. I've also thought about hamiltonian paths which is closer to what I want but still doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Any suggestions on what sort of algorithm can be used would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: Is it though? I do not need to return to the start point, just collect all of the blocks.

Comment: @JasonB It is equivalent. You can add an extra node connected to all the rest, then an optimal cycle in that graph corresponds to an optimal open path in the original, and vice versa.

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple BFS or DFS work?

Comment: @AndrewScott Apparently, the question isn't about travelling each vertex once. It is about minimizing the length of the total traversal while collecting the blocks. Hence the term "an efficient path".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has a classic name in the litterature, it is the **minimum hamiltonian walk problem**. Beware not to mistake it with the minimum hamiltonian path problem, its 'cousin', because it is much more famous, and much, much harder (finding a hamiltonian walk can be done in polynomial time, finding a hamiltonian path is NP-complete). The traveling salesman problem is the other name of the minimum hamiltonian path problem (path, not walk).

There are very few ressources on this problem, but nevertheless you can have a look at an article called 'An algorithm for finding a short closed spanning walk in a graph' by Takamizawa, Nishizeki and Saito from 1980. They provide a polynomial algorithm to find such a path.

If the paper is a bit hard to read, or the algorithm too complex to implement, then I'll suggest that you go for the [christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm), because it runs in polynomial time, and is somehow efficient (it is a 2-approximation if I remember well).

Another possible approach would be to go for a greedy algorithm, like a nearest unvisited neigbor algorithm (start somewhere, go to the nearest node that is not in the walk yet, repeat until everyone is in the walk).
Acutally, I think the easiest and maybe best simple solution is to go greedy.